# How to add a SOAP parameter to a C# service reference

Tags: c#, soap, attributes, wsdl

I have created service references in `Visual Studio 2017` from `WSDL`'s provided by our client. One of them requires an attribute/parameter like:

```
<Item ActionCode="02">
```

I'm new to SOAP services and can't figure out how to add the ActionCode.  I see it in the object browser and in the References.cs.

Here is my code so far (which works for a similar call with no attribute):

```
BYDUpdateTimeSvc.EmployeeTimeCreateRequestMessage_sync req = new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.EmployeeTimeCreateRequestMessage_sync()
{
    BasicMessageHeader = new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.BusinessDocumentBasicMessageHeader(),
    EmployeeTime = new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.EmployeeTimeCreateRequest()
    {
        EmployeeTimeAgreementItemUUID = new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.UUID { Value = rec.employeeTimeAgreement },
        Item = new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.EmployeeTimeCreateRequestItem[1]
        {
            new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.EmployeeTimeCreateRequestItem()
            {
                TypeCode = activityCode,
                PaymentTypeCode = locationCode,
                EmployeeTimeValidity = _dateValidity
            }
        }
    }
};
```

How do I add that parameter/attribute?

Comment: My post was edited so it may not be clear that I'm trying to add an attribute/parameter to the <Item> element so that when it's sent i looks like <Item ActionCode="02">.  I can't figure out how that's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about the API you are using.
That said, have you tried setting the property using object initializer syntax.

```
BYDUpdateTimeSvc.EmployeeTimeCreateRequestMessage_sync req = new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.EmployeeTimeCreateRequestMessage_sync()
{
    BasicMessageHeader = new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.BusinessDocumentBasicMessageHeader(),
    EmployeeTime = new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.EmployeeTimeCreateRequest()
    {
        EmployeeTimeAgreementItemUUID = new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.UUID { Value = rec.employeeTimeAgreement },
        Item = new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.EmployeeTimeCreateRequestItem[1]
        {
            new BYDUpdateTimeSvc.EmployeeTimeCreateRequestItem()
            {
                TypeCode = activityCode,
                PaymentTypeCode = locationCode,
                EmployeeTimeValidity = _dateValidity
            }, // added comma
            ActionCode = "02"; // set action code here
        }            
    }
};
```

Comment: I had thought that's what I needed to do as well.  But you made me think some more and in the end read more carefully.  The WSDL provides for both a CREATE and an UPDATE.  In my code above I'm using the BYDUpdateTimeSvc reference but was referring to the wrong classes with 'TimeCreate' in them instead of the 'TimeUpdate' version of them.  Changed all that and 'ActionCode' was then available.  Even though you couldn't help me directly you caused me to figure it out.  So you get all the credit (after the 24 bounty period passes).  Thanks!